# Typescript to JSON Schema or vice versa - with code completion/navigation in Intellij

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, jsonschema

We are using OpenAI function calls for various parts of our Typescript project, and this involves creating a JSON Schema for the response format you would like OpenAI to respond in.

Once we have the response, we then want to interact with this object in Typescript again, so at the moment I am effectively creating two models with the same information.

It seems like 'json-schema-to-ts' was created to resolve this scenario. From their examples:

```
const dogSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: { type: "string" },
    age: { type: "integer" },
    hobbies: { type: "array", items: { type: "string" } },
    favoriteFood: { enum: ["pizza", "taco", "fries"] },
  },
  required: ["name", "age"],
} as const;

type Dog = FromSchema<typeof dogSchema>;
```

However, when I come to use this example in Typescript, eg:

```
let dog: Dog
dog. // <---- I get no auto completion at this point
```

As above I get no auto completion showing me the properties of this schema when using this type. Am I doing something wrong?

What I would IDEALLY like is to be able to define a Typescript interface or class, and convert this to a JSON Schema at runtime to pass to OpenAI, and then cast the response back to this interface/class, is this possible?

Comment: I do get completion when using your example; doyou have Typescript language service enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**?

Comment: @lena I do. As per my answer completion works perfectly for me using Typebox, so I have no idea why json-schema-to-ts was not playing nicely for me...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like TypeBox (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinclair/typebox) has the functionality I require.

It's not quite as convenient as starting with Typescript interfaces (I'm assuming this isn't possible as they don't exist at runtime?), but the definitions are concise enough, and the IDE is recognising the correct model when converting to a Typescript type (something that was not working for me with 'json-schema-to-ts').

Comment: You can start with TypeScript interfaces with a few libraries, such as typia and typescript-json-schema (they work by using the TypeScript compiler API to inspect the types and either generate or transform your code). However, I'm not sure I'd recommend it, depending on how long your code needs to be maintained for - it seems a bit fragile.